# How do implement back Link in JSP page?

Tags: spring, web-services

I use a 'backlink' parameter to keep the last link (which can be dynamic) and include the link in the back button `href` on the next jsp page. What is the better solution for this?.'referer' tag is not possible cause the "back" page is not always the immediate last page. Also `History.goBack()` is not usable here.

Comment: You asked for a solution: to be honest: the browser has a back button, your application does not need a second one.

Comment: @Ralph `History.goBack()` is not usable here. TO must describe the problem in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to send page1 URL through a request variable, get on page2 and create link with it.

1st JSP:

```
String backURL = current page URL;
request.setAttribute("backURL", backURL);
```

2nd JSP:

```
String backURL = request.getAttribute("backURL").toString();

<a href="backURL">Back</a>
```

`History.goBack()` gets contents from cache, that might cause issues in proper functioning of some of the controls. 
Redirection should always be performed relying on server side to fetch updated contents.

Comment: When the back link is sent as a GET Parameter, a link can be constructed by an attacker where this back-link parameter is replaced by JavaScript code to run cross site scripting attack. Then the attacker's JavaScript is inserted into href parameter. Thus, one needs to be careful with this solution.

Comment: Yeah, so better to send it as hidden field value.